# Merge [linux-kernel] into [linux]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

Because Linux **is** the kernel.
(A full operating system based on Linux is not normally called Linux; it's GNU/Linux)

From the tag wiki (tag usage section), it seems [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) is meant to be used for questions about the Linux (not about things that may or may not come together with Linux), therefore these 2 tags are duplicates of each other.

Since Linux is, by definition, the name of the kernel, `-kernel` is unnecessary, so the merged tag should be just [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux).

Comment: [linux] is a garbage dump, much like [windows], [macos], [facebook], etc.  SO users have always figured out ways to avoid getting dragged into  those dumps.  Do stop trying to help them.

Comment: @HansPassant what does it mean — "garbage dump"? A tag which contains questions which should all be auto-closed/deleted? Why a garbage dump is even necessary if questions may be closed or deleted? It looks like unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 8):

Strictly speaking you're correct...but the tag wikis for both *beg* to differ.

For [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux):

> The [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) tag on Stack Overflow is generally used for questions
>   about:
>
> - programming against the APIs supplied by the operating system
> - the implementation of the kernel
> - programming tools and techniques for use *on* a GNU/Linux system.
>
> Notable questions that probably don't belong are:
>
> - questions about using a desktop or laptop GNU/Linux system are better directed towards Super User, Unix & Linux, or Ask Ubuntu.
> - questions about administering GNU/Linux systems for other users and networking GNU/Linux systems in a context more complicated than a
>     minimal home network are better directed towards Server Fault.

For [linux-kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-kernel):

> This tag is for questions about the internals of the Linux kernel
>   itself - particularly about writing code that runs within the context
>   of the kernel (like kernel modules or drivers).
>
> Questions about writing userspace code in Linux should generally be
>   tagged [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) instead. Since the internals of the Linux kernel
>   are constantly changing, it is helpful to include the precise kernel
>   version(s) that you are interested in.

...So despite the fact that there is a technicality in play here, the tag is ***incredibly*** well disambiguated.

Comment: Please note that the tag wiki for [tag:linux] was amended since the answer was created and as a result the quoted text does not match the latest version of the source.